# I can't seem to make toggle switch work on my library app

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to finish my Library Application. I have forgot to add a read button. Now I am trying to add a switch toggle. I have added it to the popUp form as well as the row.innerHTML in the DOM.

I have set the value to "yes", but when I am toggling it on the popUp form it does not actually work. **When I submit the form as "mark as read" checked it still adds it as "unchecked". How can I go on about fixing this error?**

```js
// ############ Selectors ############

//Add a book form pop up
const newBtn = document.querySelector('#newBtn');
//add the new book to the library
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addBtn');
// close span
const closeSpan = document.querySelector('.close');
// display the new book
const display = document.querySelector('.display-lib');
//############ Listeners ############

// pop up the modal
newBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = "block";
})

// closes the form
closeSpan.addEventListener('click', function () {
    popUp.style.display = "none";
})

// closes the form when you click anywhere on the window
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target == popUp) {
        popUp.style.display = "none";
    }
})



class Book {
    constructor(title, author, pages, notes, read) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.read = read;

    }
}

let myLibrary = [];

class UI {
    displayBook() {
        //storing the books

        for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
            addBookToLibrary(myLibrary[i]);
        }
    }

    addBookToLibrary(book) {
        const shelf = document.querySelector('#book-list');
        const row = document.createElement('th');


        row.innerHTML = `
        <div class="book"> 
            <div class="title">Title: ${book.title}</div>
                 <p class="author">Author: ${book.author}</p>
                 <p class="pages">Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
                 <p class="pages">Notes: ${book.notes}</p>
            <span class="read_toggle_label">Mark as read:</span>
         <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id='read' name='read'>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
         </label>
             <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
        </div>
            `;

    if (book.read) {
        row.querySelector('#read').checked = true;
    }

        //delete the book
        const dlt = row.querySelector('.delete');
        dlt.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            //first get the UI 
            const ui = new UI();
            ui.deleteBook(e.target);
            ui.showAlertDelete('book removed', 'success');
        })


        shelf.appendChild(row);
    }



    clearFields() {
        document.querySelector('#title').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#author').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#pages').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#notes').value = '';
    }
    deleteBook(target) {
        if (target.className === 'delete') {
            target.parentElement.remove();
        }

    }
    // the alert prototoype function
    showAlert(message, className) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = `alert ${className}`;
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        const form = document.querySelector('#form');
        form.appendChild(div);
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
        }, 3000);

    }
    showAlertDelete(message, className) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = `alert ${className}`;
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        const form = document.querySelector('.content');
        form.appendChild(div);
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
        }, 3000);

    }

}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value,
        author = document.querySelector('#author').value,
        pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value,
        notes = document.querySelector('#notes').value,
        read = document.querySelector('#read').checked;


    const ui = new UI();
    if (title === '' || author === '' || pages === '' || notes === '') {
        ui.showAlert('Fill in the all the fields', 'error');
    } else {
        const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, notes, read);
        ui.addBookToLibrary(newBook);
        myLibrary.push(newBook);
        //function to clear input after submitted
        ui.clearFields();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;

}

p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1rem;

}

body {
    background-color: #41b3a3;
    height: 100vh;
}

.success,
.error {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.error {
    background: rgb(190, 0, 0);
}

.success {
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
}


/* Modal popup box  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp */

/* The Modal (background) */
input#title {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;

}

input#author {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;

}

input#pages {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {

    transform: scale(2);
}

#popUp {

    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
    font-size: 30px;

}

/* Modal Content/Box */
#form {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 20%;
    /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.mark_as_read {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;

}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {

    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #41b3a3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#switch_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Styles for the added book */
.book {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #56c49e;
}

.title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.author {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pages {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">

    <h1 class="title">A Book Library</h1>
    <p>A library project where you can store your books, coded for the Odin Project</p>




    <div id="addBtn_container" class="has-text-centered">
      <a id="newBtn" class="button is-primary is-inverted">Add a New Book</a>
    </div>

    <div id="popUp">
      <form id='form'>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <ledgend>New Book</ledgend>
        <div id='textInput'>
          <p><input type='text' id='title' name='title' placeholder='Title'></p>
          <p><input type='text' id='author' name='author' placeholder='Author'></p>
          <p><input type='text' id='pages' name='pages' placeholder='Pages'></p>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Additional Notes</label>
          <div class="control">
            <textarea id='notes' class="textarea" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="switch_container">
          <span class="mark_as_read">Mark as read: </span>
          <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id='read' name='read'>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
          <button class="button  is-success  is-rounded is-pulled-right" type='submit' form='form'
            id='addBtn'>Add</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>MY BOOKS</h1>
  <div class="display-lib">
    <table>
      <tbody id="book-list">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  </tbody>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#read').value.checked` should be `document.querySelector('#read').checked`. In the future being specific as to problems will help you get better answers. "does not actually work" is not specific and doesn't say what you expect to happen and what's not meeting your expectations. I still don't know what "not actually work" means but noticed the mistake in your code by searching fo "read".

Comment: I thought I already left it as ".checked" however when I submit the form as "mark as read" checked, it still adds it as "unchecked". I made my question a little bit clear

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the first part of my comment, the code block you posted has `.value.checked`. That's not a valid way to look up a checkbox value.

Comment: I understood it. I just thought I had already left it as "document.querySelector('#read').checked" :) As a beginner, reading over and over again for hours melt my brain.

Answer (score 0):

First you incorrectly save checkbox state in `book` object, it supposed to be:
`read = document.querySelector('#read').checked` (no value key)

And finally You have nothing that would handle `read` data in `book` object in the `addBookToLibrary()`.

Just add after `row.innerHTML`:

```
if (book.read)
  row.querySelector('#read').checked = true;
```

P.S.
For better performance, you should use `getElementById()` instead of `querySelector()` when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the code.
However, when I toggle "mark as read" while I am adding the book in the pop up modal, console log throws an error "row.getElementById is not a function". But, if I dont touch "mark as read" toggle switch, it automatically adds as checked.

What I want is to change the "read" parametre in the added book based on the toggle switch on the pop up form.

Comment: @Metalwell hmmm something I didn't know myself, `getElementById()` is not available if element is not added into DOM. `querySelector()` on other hand works fine...updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I should have tried it myself first. But now It is working as I want it to. Appreciate the help so far!